# Wordpress: Create a custom page through widget

Tags: wordpress, templates, widget

so I am working on a website for a friend right now. Right now I'm trying to figure out a good way to build a customizable staff section. So far I just created a custom template with a widget area, wrote a simple widget with name, age etc.

This works pretty decent so far. Now I'd like to have an extra "about me" page for each staff member.

Can I create a custom page somehow through a widget? Or would there be a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [custom post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). Just like pages and regular posts you can create your own type of posts. You can create a 'staff' post type. This will add an extra menu item in your Wordpress backend for staff members. There are also multiple plugins available to create post types without using code, but if you can code I would recommend do it yourself. Simply put the following code in your theme's functions.php:

```
function create_staff_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'staff',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Staff' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Staff member' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => [
          'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail',
          'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields',
          'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes',
          'post-formats'
      ]
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_staff_post_type' );
```

After creating the post type you should reset the friendly URL's. You can do that by going to `settings`->`permalinks` and click the 'save' button (no need to change any option). This will make sure your new mysite.com/staff URL works.

This page will use your default archive page (or, if you don't have an archive page your index.php file) to generate the overview. If you want a customized template, simply create archive-staff.php and create your custom loop there. Same goes for the detail page, single-staff.php will give you a template for just this specific page.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much.  So I can basically just add people there, and list the people on the staff page? Also, using this way, is there an easy way of adding "fields" like picture, age, etc. To then implement these into the page? Basically so I can style them with css instead of dealing with the WYSIWYG Wordpress Editor.

Comment: Yes exactly. To create fields you can use the default Wordpress custom fields (https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields), though this is not super user friendly, it is very easy to implement. Another option would be to create your own custom meta boxes. There is also a plugin you can use (https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) who does it for you, but it is a bit bloated.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about Custom Fields but the option isn't showing up in the custom post type screen options :/. Do I need to use a plugin for that? Or declare it somewhere?

Comment: You can add an extra argument 'supports' to the array where you can set which sections need to be available. I will update my answer with all options (feel free to remove the ones you don't need). Also don't forget to accept my answer as the right answer if you feel it is :).